# Loading embedded resource .rtf file into richtextbox on load C#

Tags: c#-4.0, resources, richtextbox, rtf, embedded-resource

Ok so I read about loading an embedded rtf into a rich text box and I am trying to do it when the form loads. The form is not the main form, it is a second form that loads when a control is clicked. This is what I have on the form when it loads:

```
private void Credits_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Assembly creditAssm = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
    using (Stream creditStream =
    creditAssm.GetManifestResourceStream("YDisplayView.credits.rtf"))
    {
        creditsRichTextBox.LoadFile(creditStream, RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText);
    }
}
```

In the solution explorer the rtf file shows as a resource and the build action is set to embedded resource.

when I click the button to load the form, it shows as expected, but nothing happens. The contents of the rtf doesn't seem to show :/

I can only assume I am doing it wrong :(

Any help for this newbie would be appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I figured it out:

```
creditAssm.GetManifestResourceStream("YDisplayView.credits.rtf"))
```

needed to be:

```
creditAssm.GetManifestResourceStream("YDisplayView.Resources.credits.rtf"))
```

***Edit:*** For some reason this time around I can't get the above code to work but I found another one that did so hopefully either/or will be of some help to new coders out there :)

```
string rtf = yourAppName.Properties.Resources.yourEmbeddedRTFName;
        yourRichTextBox.Rtf = rtf;
```

Answer (score 5):

I wanted to create an rtf help file named Help.rtf and have it stored as a resource and so it could be loaded when a Help form was loaded without having a Help.rtf hanging around the application folders.

I found I needed to add the rtf file to the resources through the menu's **Project-> 'Your name space' Properties...** then navigate to Resources tab, then Add Item etc etc... before the intellisense would offer the rtf file in it's drop-down list when I typed 'My.Resource.' Now, the list of resources including the Help file I added shows up (without extension, which is normal).

In short, once this was done, then the following worked:

```
RichTextBox1.rtf = My.Resources.Help
```

Apparently it wasn't enough just to Drag&Drop, Copy or even add the file using the 'Solution Explorer'!

Spent 3 days on this problem so I hope someone finds it usefull.